# Retrieving data from server database in IBM worklight

Tags: javascript, ajax, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an app in IBM worklight. By Ajax I have to Connect to website and retrieve data from it but it gives thisd error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null at file:///data/data/com.Test/files/www/default/Test.html:80

How can I fix it? My code is this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>



<html>
<head>
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Test.css">
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    txt="";
   // x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Id");

var table = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table");
var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(tds);
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  alert(tds[i].innerHTML);
}



  /*    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
      }  */
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.marketing.com/msb_en.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">

<h2>MCollection:</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">collection</button>
<!--<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com.pk')" />  -->
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Test.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my line 80 this is

```
var table = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

Comment: I do not see a table in the HTML... thus it gets null...?

Comment: yes...plz suggest me some to solve it..but does not get any thing from  url which i give

Comment: If there is no table element in the HTML, how do you expect to retrieve it? There is no table element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like xmlDoc is null when you try to use. Make sure your server is returning what you are expecting and that you are accessing the data in the response properly.

A couple of suggestions not directly related to your question. jQuery is already loaded in your app. You may want to consider using its AJAX functionality rather than using XMLHttpRequest directly.

Also if you're using Worklight, you could consider using an HTTPAdapter instead of AJAX all together. If you're not leveraging the functionality that Worklight provides beyond just a browser to write your code in then maybe you should look at other options for your platform.